# How do I fix Netbeans' invalid source release?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am getting this error when attempting to run a java program. I am using Neatbeans IDE 18.

```
error: invalid source release 16 with --enable-preview
  (preview language features are only supported for release 18)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I downloaded Netbeans IDE 19, and received the same error message.

Comment: Always search for your answer before posting.